# FAIL. Reason: SafeMath: subtraction overflow When trying to deposit to Geist on FTM

Tags: solidity, fantom, foundry

Keep getting an overflow randomly when trying to deposit to geist. This error randomly occurs and I cannot explain why. Has anyone else experienced this behaviour?

Here is a link to the repo:https://github.com/ChinmayGopal931/Help/blob/main/src/test/SpookySwap.t.sol

I test with Foundry

Comment: What's geist? Can you show the contract code?

Comment: Geist is the main lending provider on Fantom.

Comment: Do you have a transaction hash with the error?

Comment: @Ismael  Added repo Above!